# stat returns `No such file or directory`, run under java exec

Tags: java, bash, exec, stat

I want to call `stat` in *Java*, using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stat /*")
```

But always get exit code -1 and:

```
stat: cannot stat `/*': No such file or directory
```

Run `stat /*` in *bash* is OK, and this is also OK:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("stat /")
```

Has `stat /*` in *Java* a different behavior as in *bash*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat /*` works in the command line because the shell interprets the `*`.
You should try running through bash, e.g., `bash -c stat /*`